# source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Tags: android

How do I prevent the two warnings below from generating an error that stops the build process ?

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 77 source files to /Users/andev/Workspace/android/products/myproject/1.0/Facebook/bin/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
    [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
    [javac] error: warnings found and -Werror specified
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 3 warnings
```

Comment: Are you using minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion = 3 in your Manifest?

Comment: no, the smallest minSdkVersion was 4. I bumped it to 8 but the warning still shows.

Comment: I guess something remained set in your `project.properties` file (like: `target=android-3`). You can edit it manually (open it into the Text Editor)

Comment: I avoided that problem by using in my build script `android update project --target android-19 --path ../Facebook --name Facebook` for all the libraries (in this case facebook) and main project.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Another possibility (which will fix it for *all* Android builds made with Ant), is to tweak the default parameters for the `-compile` task in `<android-sdk>\tools\ant\build.xml`.

At the `<!-- compilation options -->` section, you can either set the compiler flags:

```
<property name="java.compilerargs" value="-Xlint:-options" />
```

or, alternatively, change the source and target parameters:

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.6" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.6" />
```

As of now, `1.6` is enough to avoid the warning.

Comment: The latter seems much more cleaner (`java.target` and `java.source`). What side effects does `-Xlint:-options` have?

Comment: `java.target` and `java.source` worked for me, thanks

Comment: But, `"/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/bin"` or `"/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant"` there is no build.xml file???

Comment: Changes nothing for me.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to build, I created a file `ant.properties` in the facebook project (first project that is compiled) with the contents :

```
java.compilerargs=-Xlint:-options
```

Comment: How does this get around the `1.5` warning?

Answer (score 4):

This is set in the `${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml` file. At the beginning of the file are many `property` settings, e.g.

```xml
<!-- compilation options -->
<property name="java.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="java.target" value="1.5" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.5" />
<property name="java.compilerargs" value="" />
<property name="java.compiler.classpath" value="" />
```

Also at the beginning of this file is a comment

> ```
> At the beginning of the file is a list of properties that can be overridden
> by adding them to your ant.properties (properties are immutable, so their
> first definition sticks and is never changed).
> ```

So, in order to override any property in general and source value and target value in particular, you can put these properties into the ant.properties file in your project directory

```
java.source=1.6
java.target=1.6
```

This overrides the default settings in `${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml` and thus prevents the warnings.

Comment: Although the global change is useful, I prefer this answer since the change is reflected locally and explicitly in the project.