# Error building debug app Android

Tags: android, ant, adb

I'm trying to build my app using command line:

`ant debug`

I'm having this error:

```
[javac] Compiling 96 source files to /Users/mauricio/Development/Eclipse/Libraries/facebook-android-sdk/facebook/bin/classes
[javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
[javac] error: warnings found and -Werror specified
[javac] 1 error
[javac] 3 warnings
```

How do I ignore those warnings? It is clear that it is crashing because it got a warning.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331705/source-value-1-5-is-obsolete-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-release)